# PHP is giving back response but not showing the data sent through volley from android

Tags: php, android

I am sending email of user from my android app to server through volley POST Method and then getting back the email from PHP response.In php, I am echoing the email, but it is not showing that. Not getting why? Please help. My android code is...

```
String url ="http://www.url.com/email.php";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    StringRequest  stRequest = new StringRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.v("changeLocation ","********response is " +response.toString());
                    mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {

                }
            })
    { //Code to send parameters to server
        @Override
        protected Map getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email","example@gmail.com");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stRequest);`
```

My Php code is

```
<?php
 $user_email=$_POST['email'];
 echo "Email is $user_email";
?>
```

Comment: try adding a **log** statement inside `onErrorResponse` as well and check if its getting called

Comment: No, onErrorResponse  is not getting called

Comment: Is onResponse getting called, if yes what is the response?

Comment: yes...response is.. ********response is email is example@gmail.com

Comment: I assume that is the correct response, is your textview empty? Is that your issue?

Comment: issue is php should echo "email is example@gmail.com" but it  is showing only "email is " i.e.$user_email is null

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by removing "throws AuthFailureError" from getParams()

```
@Override
    protected Map getParams() 
    {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email","example@gmail.com");

        return params;
    }
```